# Database distribution in AlwaysOn

Tags: sql-server, replication, availability-groups, clustering, distributed-databases

Good morning all,
I have an on Always On SQL server configuration where transactional replication is configured
If I open SSMS I find that the distribution database is set to AlwaysOn on then I cannot find the synchronized word.
[image]
thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would not rely on Object Explorer (or the AG dashboard) in SSMS to determine the status. Use the DMVs directly (or create your own dashboards against them). Something like this:

```
SELECT 
  d.name, 
  AGName = COALESCE(ag.name, 'N/A'), 
  drs.synchronization_state_desc, 
  ar.replica_server_name
FROM sys.databases AS d
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states AS drs
  ON d.database_id = drs.database_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.availability_groups AS ag
  ON drs.group_id = ag.group_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.availability_replicas AS ar 
  ON drs.replica_id = ar.replica_id;
```

I suspect this specific limitation is just that they didn't add the `display sync status` logic into the code path that renders the `System Databases` node. The fact that is it missing is [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/configure-distribution-availability-group?view=sql-server-ver15), but without an explanation why:

> SSMS does not show Distribution Database as synchronizing/synchronized, when distribution database is added to an availability group.